# Can I add a new chrome:// page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension that consists on some kind of alternative bookmarks system. I need some way to show the links I have stored on my extension.

I have try to create a "chrome://" page [overriding](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html) a "links" adding the next code to my manifest.json file.

```
[...]
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "links": "myPage.html"
},
[...]
```

But this only works for certain pages ("newpage", "bookmarks" and "history") :(.

There is any way of creating custom "chrome://" pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite clear in [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html):

> For **pageToOverride**, substitute one of the following:
>
> - bookmarks
> - history
> - newtab

So, the answer is "**No**, you **cannot** create custom `chrome://` pages"!